# Systemctl: Argument list too long

Tags: centos, systemd, check-mk, xinetd

I'm running `Centos 7` and need to install a `check_mk` agent to get machine stats. I have successfully installed the agent in many others `Centos 7` of the same cluster through an `rpm` package but with the current machine I get this output:

```
Running transaction
Warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum.
  Installing : check-mk-agent-1.5.0p9-1.noarch                                                                                                                                                             1/1 
Activating startscript of xinetd
Note: Forwarding request to 'systemctl enable xinetd.service'.
Failed to execute operation: Argument list too long
Starting xinetd...
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start xinetd.service
Failed to start xinetd.service: Argument list too long
See system logs and 'systemctl status xinetd.service' for details.
  Verifying  : check-mk-agent-1.5.0p9-1.noarch                                                                                                                                                             1/1 

Installed:
  check-mk-agent.noarch 0:1.5.0p9-1
```

Also noticed the system can't get to work any `systemd` new service. I made a junk service for testing purposes, its config file at `/etc/systemd/system` is named `test.service` and simply calls a python script under `/root/test_service/`.
This is the service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Example systemd service.

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/root/test_service/service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and this is the `python` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time

i = 0
while True:
        print(i)        
        time.sleep(2)
        i += 1
```

Run `systemctl start test.service` I get the error:

```
Failed to start test.service: Argument list too long
See system logs and 'systemctl status test.service' for details.
```

In addition, `systemd` seems to be properly working as I have plenty of others services up and running. Also tried starting a `xinetd` service resulting in same error.

Any clue would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [known bug](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7119)

Try [pruning](https://ma.ttias.be/clear-systemd-journal/) your journal